# Stop redirecting page if the url have control character

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to check if the URL has control character code like 0x00,0x01..0x1f and 0x7f

```
example.com/test.php?status0x01Http../
```

If it has need to redirect to 404 page .If no such character exist redirect to the accessed page.

I want to achieve this in `.htaccess`.
Tried

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)>$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

above code remove all the character

Comment: What did you try, what problem did you run into?

Comment: RewriteRule applies the pattern to the path component of the URL only. If you want to do anything based on query string contents, you need to use a RewriteCond to do that.

Comment: "above code remove all the character" - the above code wouldn't do that. `sample.com/test.php?status0x01Http../` - presumably by `0x01` you mean the ordinal character with hex code 01, so the URL does not literally contain the characters as stated in your example?

Answer (score 3):

From your example, these *control characters* appear in the query string only. To form a valid HTTP request these chars would need to be URL-encoded (ie. %-encoded as `%HH`) in the request. So an actual request would be of the form:

```
example.com/test.php?status%01Http../
```

We can check the `QUERY_STRING` server variable using a mod_rewrite *condition*, which remains %-encoded.

For example, you could trigger a 404 for such URLs using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %([01][0-9A-F]|7F) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

This will need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, before any existing mod_rewrite directives. As a general rule, any *blocking* directives should be first.

> If no such character exist redirect to the accessed page

There is nothing that needs to be done in this respect, the above rule simply isn't triggered and the request falls through and is processed normally.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> example.com/test.php?status0x01Http../
> ```

Although it would seem (from more recent questions) that you may be referring to the literal characters `0x01` etc. These are not "control characters" in the URL, they are simply the sequence of characters `0`, `x`, `0` and `1`. etc.

If this is the case then you can modify the above rule to read:

```
# Check the query string only for this sequence of chars
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} 0x([01][0-9A-F]|7F) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

If this sequence of characters also appears in the URL-path then you shouldn't need to do anything as I would expect your application to already be triggering a 404 when the URL does not resolve. However, you could check for this sequence of characters anywhere in the URL by checking against `THE_REQUEST` instead.

For example:

```
# Check the entire URL for this sequence of chars
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} 0x([01][0-9A-F]|7F) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

Comment: This is checking only in query string

Comment: @user3386779 Yes, this only checks the query string, as per the example in your question. If there is more information then please edit your question to include this. What are the actual URLs you are receiving? If you are literally seeing `0x01` in the URL (as per your example) then this is not a "control character" - I addressed this in a comment on your question, but received no response?

Comment: @user3386779 I've updated my answer with respect to matching the character sequence `0x01` etc. (rather than the "control characters" themselves). I've also covered matching these characters anywhere in the URL, not just in the query string.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. I am posting here 2 set of htaccess file, keep either of them ONLY not both of them.

***1st one is*** a Generic one where on any url which has .php followed by query string it will work.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(?:[^.]*)\.php\?.*%([01][0-9A-F]|7F) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

***2nd one is*** a specific case which works on url which contains test.php followed by a query string it will work.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/test\.php\?.*%([01][0-9A-F]|7F) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also keep these rules at top of your htaccess rules file.