# Pattern for matching a rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have tried to write the htaccess for the set of rules.below is the rule pattern I want to match

```
0x00|0x01|0x02|0x03|0x04|0x05|0x06|0x07|0x08|0x09|0x0A|0x0B|0x0C|
0x0D|0x0E|0x0F|0x10|0x11|0x12|0x13|0x14|0x15|0x16|0x17|0x18|0x19|
0x1A|0x1B|0x1C|0x1D|0x1E|0x1F|0x7F
```

I have tried as `0x([01-09]|[0A-0F]|[10-19]|[1A-1F]|7F)`

Comment: What are you trying to match using `.htaccess`? What rule are you trying to write? (What request are you trying to match?)

Comment: Please edit to including an example. Be sure to show what is to be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misled yourself because as a human, you know that "01", "02", etc are a sequence of numbers. Regular expressions don't care about numbers, they care about **characters**. `[01-09]` doesn't mean "01 to 09", it means "0; or 1 to 0; or 9" - which clearly doesn't make sense.

If you break it down character by character, you have:

- "0"
- "x"
- "0" or "1" (in regex terms, the set `[01]`)
- "0" to "9" (the character range `[0-9]`), or "A" to "F" (`[A-F]`)
- plus the special case of "0x7F"

So you could for instance write:

```
0x[01]([0-9]|[A-F])|0x7F
```

You can combine the two ranges into one, giving:

```
0x[01][0-9A-F]|0x7F
```

Sharing the `0x` doesn't actually make it any shorter:

```
0x([01][0-9A-F]|7F)
```

Answer (score 2):

> `0x00|0x01|0x02|0x03|0x04|0x05|0x06|0x07|0x08|0x09|0x0A|0x0B|0x0C| 0x0D|0x0E|0x0F|0x10|0x11|0x12|0x13|0x14|0x15|0x16|0x17|0x18|0x19| 0x1A|0x1B|0x1C|0x1D|0x1E|0x1F|0x7F`

This is already a regular expression. You can use this exactly as written (as part of a regex).

But it can be simplified to:

```
0x([01][0-9A-F]|7F)
```

You may want to make this regex case-insensitive by using the `(?i)` mode modifier. For example:

```
(?i)0x([01][0-9A-F]|7F)
```

Or use the `NC` (`nocase`) flag with a mod_rewrite directive in `.htaccess`.

Incidentally, this is basically the same regex as used in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70949686/369434) to your earlier question:
[Stop redirecting page if the url have control character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70938492/stop-redirecting-page-if-the-url-have-control-character)